# Result from ActiveRoute needed for two independent succeeding queries

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, angular-router, switchmap

What is the best practice when I need to use switchMap on an Observable twice (independent queries). I need the Id returned from activeRoute.ParamMap... for two independent queries. For only one query, I would do the following:

```
this.route.paramMap
.switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
  this.service.getSomeInformation(params.get('id')));
```

and now I need the Id returned from the route for another query

```
this.route.paramMap
.switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
  this.AnotherService.getSomeMoreInformation(params.get('id')));
```

so I need the Id extracted from paramMap as input for service and for     anotherService.

What is the best practice? Just chain them? The timing of the Observables from Service and AnotherService is irrelevant.

Since this is my first question here, please let me know what I can do better in the next question(s).

Thank you,
steffen

Comment: store the id value in one observable, and then use that + switchMap to use the services?

Answer (score 1):

You can use merge operator to combine the other observables

```
this.route.paramMap
.switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
    Rx.Observable.merge(service1(params.get('id'), service2(params.get('id'))
)
```